# Secure Version of wsprintf()?

Tags: c++, windows, msvcrt, fortify, crt

Like we have secure version for `_stprintf` i.e `stprintf_s` for the hp fortify bufferoverflow
warning, So what we can use instead of  `wsprintf`()? I tried `wsprintf_s`, Its not working.

And Can any one please explain the difference b/w  `_stprintf`  and `wsprintf`? Or we can use `stprintf_s` as a secure version for `wsprintf` .

Comment: [swprintf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

The options are documented under [wsprintf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wsprintfw):

> **Note**  Do not use. Consider using one of the following functions instead: [StringCbPrintf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcbprintfw), [StringCbPrintfEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcbprintfexw), [StringCchPrintf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcchprintfw), or [StringCchPrintfEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcchprintfexw). See Security Considerations.

If you would rather want to use a secure function that more closely resembles `wsprintf`, go with [swprintf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l) or [_snwprintf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-s-snprintf-s-l-snwprintf-s-snwprintf-s-l).

`_stprintf` is a preprocessor macro, that maps the call to either the ANSI or UNICODE version. The mapping table is documented at [sprintf, _sprintf_l, swprintf, _swprintf_l, __swprintf_l](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-sprintf-l-swprintf-swprintf-l-swprintf-l):

| TCHAR.H routine | _UNICODE & _MBCS not defined | _MBCS defined | _UNICODE defined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| _stprintf | sprintf | sprintf | _swprintf |

The mapping table for [_stprintf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l):

| TCHAR.H routine | _UNICODE & _MBCS not defined | _MBCS defined | _UNICODE defined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| _stprintf_s | sprintf_s | sprintf_s | swprintf_s |